# why constrainlayout not showing exactly as real device

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am developing new app but my preview window showing different and real device different I did not understand what is the problem

below my current layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#451C80">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/getStarted"
        style="@style/password"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textAppearance="@style/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/getStarted"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/set_password"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        style="@style/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="Confirm Password"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.167"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/username_edittext"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="506dp"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="316dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/username_edittext"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

current screen from preview window in android studio
[image: preview screen]

screenshot from real device
[image: screenshot from real device]

I want to know exactly where I am making mistake what I am making wrong what I have to do in order to implement correctly constrainlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have not given constraints properly.**

Don't use this property `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` to arrange views, understand`layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`,`layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`,`layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` **property** to arrange views vertically.

You can also use `LinearLayout` if UI is quite simple and If you use `ConstraintLayout` you have to give **proper constraints** so that ui will not look different in device as well as in preview

I have modified your code so please check below code for now so replace below code in your `xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#451C80">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/getStarted"
            style="@style/password"
            android:layout_width="178dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textAppearance="@style/password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/getStarted"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            style="@style/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="@string/set_password"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@style/password"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:text="Confirm Password"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="318dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:background="@drawable/username_edittext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="506dp"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="316dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/username_edittext"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Comment: thank you for your answer I have problem implementing ui should I have to practice a lot or I have watch tutorials

Comment: Yes, first understand all the constraints of ConstraintLayout then try to practice at least 10 different UI designs in ConstraintLayout so you will become very good in ConstraintLayout. It's very easy you can learn in some hours. Thank you @Edgar